# Xcode Playground bugging out after Apple recommended software updates

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-playground

I recently allowed two Apple recommended updates for my MacBook Pro. One was a security update and I can't remember what the other was. I'm currently running MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6. Since the updates, I can't get Xcode Playgrounds to stay open. It just quits unexpectedly over and over again. I saw some suggestions on this site for actual Xcode projects and for Playgrounds, but none have worked. I haven't bothered starting a new app because of this problem, so I'm not sure whether or not this problem will persist into an actual Xcode project file. I'd hate to start a project and then have it die unexpectedly. Any suggestion for another Apple glitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, quit, and throw away the version of Xcode that you've been using. I am assuming that you have not been using the latest Xcode version available, which is Xcode 10.2 Beta 4. The other software that you updated is clearly not working well with the non-updated Xcode version that has been giving you trouble. The best way to avoid this is to have as many things updated as possible. This is especially true if there is an obvious conflict, which seems to be the case. By rule, you should always follow Apple's recommendations for updates (including Xcode). Doing so will avoid bugs and glitches in the future for you. Happy coding.